# Is there a first person verb with a plural subject in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, grammar

I am aware of singular verbs with plural subjects in the third person, masculine, singular. Such as Exodus 4:29, but I am wondering if there is a 1cs that has a plural subject?

Feel free to add or change the tags.

> **Exodus 4:29** Moses and Aaron brought together all the elders of the Israelites,

Comment: In Exodus 4:29, the verb relates to each individually, as when saying, *Moses went, and Aaron went*; similar to how the noun *name* is used in Matthew 28:19, for instance.

Comment: Are you talking about “we” like “we prayed?”  Hebrew has 1s, 1p, 2ms, 2mp, 2fs, 2fp, 3ms, 3mp, 3fs, 3fp.

Comment: I know the ones in Exodus for the 3ps being used in 3pp, but I mean is there an instance of a 1ps being used for any plural (1pp or 3pp). such as, I [verb], and we/they (1pp or 3pp) did it.

Comment: 1ps entity used with 3pp verb - In Numbers 21:7 [MT] : "And-They-Said" (וַיֹּֽאמְר֣וּ) relating to the-People (הָעָ֨ם).

Comment: I take it you are looking for plural subjects of a singular verb. Please update your question to clarify this, otherwise people will give you examples of plural subjects and you will downvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems ambiguous to me, for I am not certain, after reading it, if you are asking for the verb to have a singular subject and a plural object, or if the verb must have a plural subject and a singular object, or if there is some other configuration you seek.

**Hebrew Subject-Verb Agreement**

As I expect you know, Hebrew verbs must agree with their nouns in gender and in number.  If for some reason they appear not to agree, it is the verb that determines the precise gender and number of the noun.  (For example, the plural "fathers" in Hebrew appears to have a feminine form, but the verb will always be masculine, showing it is actually a masculine noun.) Likewise, *plurale tantum*--words always in plural form like "elohim" (god/gods/angels/judges), "panim" (faces), "mayim" (waters), "shemayim" (heavens), etc.--will be identified by their verbs (or adjectives) as to whether they are actually plural or singular.

The usual case, of course, is that the subject and verb agree even in appearance.

Verbs, like nouns, can have a pronominal suffix.  If a plural subject and a singular pronominal suffix (object) would satisfy your search, here is one such example, from Psalm 22:16 (KJV).

[image: Interlinear of Psalm 22:16 (17)]

Consider the highlighted word for which "3cp" is indicated for the verb in addition to having the "1cs" suffix.  Also notice the first word on the second line is likewise designated as having a plural subject and singular object (pronominal suffix).

This seeming to be a very common occurrence, I do wonder if I have not perhaps misunderstood the question.  Please clarify, if need be.

In case you mean something where the subject and the verb are both grammatically plural and yet the verb is singular, we need look no farther than the second verse of the Bible.

[image: Interlinear of Genesis 1:2]

Notice that "elohim" (God) is grammatically plural, and "mayim" (waters) are also grammatically plural, and yet "mə·ra·ḥe·p̄eṯ" (was hovering) is singular.  Of course, the fact that the verb is singular helps us identify the *plurale tantum* nouns as singular.  "Elohim" is always singular when referencing only the true God.

Again, this would be a common occurrence, so if this is not the "obscure" thing you were looking to find, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Singular verb forms are used with “Elohim” which is the plural form of “eloah”.  Example:

Genesis 1:26 - And God (plural) said (singular)….

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Are there examples of 1st person plural verbs in the Ivri (עִבְרִי) / Hebrew (ἑβραιου) Tanakh?**

1. In Psalm 44:9 [MT] : **"We praised" (Hillalnu, הִלַּ֣לְנוּ)**

> "In-God we praised [ourselves] all the day, but Your Name forever spreads solo." (בֵּ֣אלֹהִים הִלַּ֣לְנוּ כָל־הַיּ֑וֹם וְשִׁמְךָ֓ | לְעוֹלָ֖ם נוֹדֶ֣ה סֶֽלָה )

2. In Psalm 75:2 [MT] : **"We thanked" (Hodinu, הוֹדִ֚ינוּ)**

> "We thanked You, God, we have thanked, and Your Name is near; they have told Your wonders." (הוֹדִ֚ינוּ לְּךָ֨ | אֱלֹהִ֗ים ה֖וֹדִינוּ וְקָר֣וֹב שְׁמֶ֑ךָ סִ֜פְּר֗וּ נִפְלְאוֹתֶֽיךָ)

**Are there examples of 3rd person plural verbs relating to a 1st person singular noun / entity in the Ivri (עִבְרִי) / Hebrew (ἑβραιου) Tanakh?**

1. In Numbers 21:7 [MT] : **"And-They-Said" (וַיֹּֽאמְר֣וּ)** relating to the-People (הָעָ֨ם).

> "The-People came to Moshe and-They-said," (וַיָּבֹא֩ הָעָ֨ם אֶל־משֶׁ֜ה וַיֹּֽאמְר֣וּ)